# jQuery - Function runs without being told to, please advise

Tags: jquery, function

I'm writing a psychology experiment in jQuery.  I want to write a function that will begin the exercise when the user presses p or q.  I have that working:

```
$(function trial() {
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 81 || e.which == 80)
        {
        $(".message").text("exercise begun (timestamp)");
        var refreshId = setTimeout(timeout, 2000);
        }
});
});
```

But I'm confused about one thing: this function, trial(), runs automatically.  I would like to have to call it, for it to run.
For instance, this function

```
function timeout(x) {
var x = trialNum
$(".message").prepend("Timeout (Trial " + x + ")<br>");
}
```

which gets called by trial() behaves itself well, it does not run unless called.  I assume this has something to do with the $ symbol, and "scope"?  All help appreciated.

Oh!  Additionally, one more question.  I was trying to make a recursive jQuery function and had a lot of trouble with it.  What's the best way to make a function call itself?

Comment: I would suggest that if you have two independent questions, you ask them separately.

Comment: I would also pay some time on the api's on jquery's website.  Their documentation is as good if not better then msdn.

Comment: Indeed, the jQuery documentation is conspicuously good for an open source project. I won't compare it to MSDN, because I wouldn't want to insult the people doing the jQuery docs.

Comment: @T.J. Crowler - Ouch, MSDN is getting better, let's put it that way.

Comment: @JonH: ;-) Marginally, perhaps. Let's just say that navigation is still a disaster, and for the company that *invented* ajax and `innerHTML`, they're astonishingly slow to, you know, actually *use* them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you're passing a reference to it into `$()` (aka [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)), which is a shortcut for the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function and runs when the DOM is loaded.

---

**Off-topic**: BTW, by doing that, you're using the function as a *right-hand value* (like something on the right-hand side of an `=` sign). That makes it a *function expression*. Since you've named the function (which is a [good thing to do](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html)), it's a *named* function expression. Those have historically not worked well in various JavaScript implementations. Most current browsers are (now) okay, except IE prior to IE9 which will create *two* completely separate functions, more here: [*Double take*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html)

Comment: Cool - but if I strip off the `$()`, how can I use the other jQuery code like `$("body").keydown` and `$(".message"`?  I don't understand how I'd structure that markup if I didn't use the `$()`.

Comment: You can use jQuery code anywhere as long as you have the jQuery library included. You don't have to do everything jQuery-related in `$(document).ready`.

Comment: The question is do you want certain things to be inside of document.ready?  That is something only you can answer based on your knowledge of the system.

Comment: I don't fully understand.  `$()` is shorthand for `$(document).ready` when I'm wrapping it around a function, but it's jquery when I'm using it in `$("body").keydown`?  Are these the same thing or different things?

Comment: Update: Tutorials all say to do ALL jQuery inside document.ready.  And when I put even a very simple jQuery statement outside of document.ready, such as this one: `$("ul li:nth-child(1)").append(numStim);`, it fails to work.  Inside document.ready, it works like a charm.  Advice?

Comment: @Tr3y: jQuery should be inside `$()` because the DOM may not be ready yet, and your selector may not find the correct elements.

Comment: @Tr3y - in most cases almost everything is inside document ready.  If you try what you posted without being in document ready you will not not get any results as the DOM is not ready at that point.  Try it out and apply `.length()` to it.  length returns the number of found selectors, and so if you test it you will see the output of an `alert` is 0 outside of the dom.

Comment: @Tr3y: *"I don't fully understand. `$()` is shorthand for `$(document).ready` when I'm wrapping it around a function, but it's jquery when I'm using it in `$("body").keydown`?"* Yes, this is one of the flaws in the jQuery API: That function does different things depending on what you pass into it. If you pass a function reference into it, it's a shortcut for `ready`. But wait, it gets worse: If you pass a string into it, what it does *depends on the string* (if it looks like HTML, it creates DOM elements; otherwise it assumes it's a selector).

Comment: @Tr3y: You *don't* have to do everything within `ready`, you just have to make sure that the elements you're accessing exist as of when the code runs. `ready` is a convenient means of doing that, but not the only means. You can just put your `script` element at the bottom of the page, [like the YUI folks recommend](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), that works just fine. Basically, if you're accessing or modifying the DOM, make sure to do it after the elements in question have been created (by putting your script after them).

Comment: All thanks be to T.J Crowder and other commenters in this response.  Answered my question in depth, +1 and checkmark.  Hope this is useful to others bemused by loose syntax (and inexperience).

Answer (score 3):

By surrounding `function trial() { ... }` with `$(` and `);`, you're calling it when the document is ready. It's shorthand for `$(document).ready(function trial() { ... });`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/ready)]</sup>*

If you don't want to do that, remove the surrounding `$(` and `);`.

Comment: +1 clearly explained very good answer and short and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, `$(function(){...code...})` is the jQuery shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...code...});` which runs as soon as the DOM has reached the `ready` state.

About your second question (it does belong in a separate question on SO, but i'll answer it anyway):

Functions in jQuery are no different than functions in JavaScript. Named functions can call themselves recursively using thier own name:

```
function foo(bar, baz)
{
  ...do some stuff...
  if (--bar)
  {
    foo(bar, baz);
  }
}
```

You'll have to be more specific as to what you want to achieve with the recursive function, and if you're going to do that, please open a separate question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`trial()` runs automatically because it is inside the `$()` function.  `$(function(){})` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

`$(function trial(){});` creates a function called `trial` in its scope, and then runs it when the DOM is ready.

Just declare the function normally:

```
function trial(){
  // Code
}
```

Or, if you want it declared when the DOM is ready, you can declare it inside `$()` (NOTE: `trial` will only exist inside the `$()` function):

```
$(function(){
    function trial(){
      // Code
    }
    trial();
});
trial(); // won't work, it's out of scope
```

Answer (score 0):

`$()` is a short cut for the DOM ready event. It just executes the function passed to it. To solve it, use `$(document).ready` itself:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function trial() {
        $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 81 || e.which == 80){
             $(".message").text("exercise begun (timestamp)");
             var refreshId = setTimeout(timeout, 2000);
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(function(){
trial = function(){
// Your code here
};
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this: `$(function trial()` will make it run automatically.

I don't know why so, but jQuery just does it like that. You are fine to just keep it as `function trial()`. As for repeating the function, just put the function name in the function and call the function externally like this:

```
function trial() {
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 81 || e.which == 80)
        {
            $(".message").text("exercise begun (timestamp)");
            var refreshId = setTimeout(timeout, 2000);
        }
    });
    trial();
}
trial();
```

However, I do not recommend this, because it will cause an infinite loop that can crash the tab.

Comment: -1 for answering a question but mentioning you dont know why.  If you dont know why its not an answer its a guess.  And no the answer is not `jquery just does it like that`.  It's because it has fired `$(document).ready` the selector being document and the action is .ready.

Comment: -1 for "it will cause a infinite loop that can crash the tab".

Comment: I did say I do not recommend it